# Sleep function in C++

Tags: c++

Is there a function like `Sleep(time);` that pauses the program for X milliseconds, but in C++?

Which header should I add and what is the function's signature?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sleep for milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184468/sleep-for-milliseconds)

Answer (score 140):

Use `std::this_thread::sleep_for`:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

std::chrono::milliseconds timespan(111605); // or whatever

std::this_thread::sleep_for(timespan);
```

There is also the complementary `std::this_thread::sleep_until`.

---

Prior to C++11, C++ had no thread concept and no sleep capability, so your solution was necessarily platform dependent. Here's a snippet that defines a `sleep` function for Windows or Unix:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <windows.h>

    void sleep(unsigned milliseconds)
    {
        Sleep(milliseconds);
    }
#else
    #include <unistd.h>
    
    void sleep(unsigned milliseconds)
    {
        usleep(milliseconds * 1000); // takes microseconds
    }
#endif
```

But a much simpler pre-C++11 method is to use `boost::this_thread::sleep`.

Comment: Hint: this_thread::sleep_for etc. is using singletons and therefore introduces STB_GNU_UNIQUEs, which - if used in a shared lib - will prevent your lib from being able to unload.

Answer (score 64):

You'll need at least C++11.

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

...

std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
```

Comment: The C++ committee is really strange if they think this is an elegant, succinct way ...

Comment: @shevy If you want to be terse you'll use `std::chrono_literals`, reducing the function argument to just `200ms`.

Comment: I place bulk of it under the headers:

`#include <chrono> 
using std::chrono::milliseconds;
#include <thread>
using std::this_thread::sleep_for;`
to keep inline code more terse:
`sleep_for(milliseconds(2000));`

Answer (score 22):

For Windows:

```
#include "windows.h" 
Sleep(10);
```

For Unix:

```
#include <unistd.h>
usleep(10)
```

Answer (score 15):

On Unix, include `#include <unistd.h>`.

The call you're interested in is `usleep()`. Which takes microseconds, so you should multiply your millisecond value by 1000 and pass the result to `usleep()`.

Answer (score 11):

Just use it...

Firstly include the `unistd.h` header file, `#include<unistd.h>`, and use this function for pausing your program execution for desired number of seconds:

```
sleep(x);
```

`x` can take any value in seconds.

If you want to pause the program for 5 seconds it is like this:

```
sleep(5);
```

It is correct and I use it frequently.

It is valid for C and C++.

Comment: @L.F. `usleep` takes microseconds, `sleep` (which this answer is written in terms of ) takes seconds -- so the answer is correct, albeit not portable

Comment: @Human-Compiler Sorry. Should’ve double checked before commenting.

Answer (score 8):

Prior to C++11, there was no portable way to do this.

A portable way is to use Boost or [Ace](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) library.
There is `ACE_OS::sleep();` in ACE.

Comment: ... and the (supposed) reason there is no portable way to do it in the standard is because the a clock's precision (smallest unit of time) is hardware-dependent or OS-dependent.  No, I don't find it a convincing reason either, but there we are.

Comment: There is no such thing as thread defined by standard... and you want sleep. Sleep is a OS provided functionality. I can have environment which does not provide me such feature.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: That is not the reason at all.  Who is it making this supposition other than yourself?  There is no standard for thread support (yest), and if there are no threads (or rather only one thread), there is no need for a thread sleep rather than a simple 'busy-wait', which can be implemented with <time.h>/<ctime>.  The support must be provided by the thread library or OS.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way I found for C++ 11 was this:

Your includes:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
```

Your code (this is an example for sleep 1000 millisecond):

```
std::chrono::duration<int, std::milli> timespan(1000);
std::this_thread::sleep_for(timespan);
```

The duration could be configured to any of the following:

```
std::chrono::nanoseconds   duration</*signed integer type of at least 64 bits*/, std::nano>
std::chrono::microseconds  duration</*signed integer type of at least 55 bits*/, std::micro>
std::chrono::milliseconds  duration</*signed integer type of at least 45 bits*/, std::milli>
std::chrono::seconds       duration</*signed integer type of at least 35 bits*/, std::ratio<1>>  
std::chrono::minutes       duration</*signed integer type of at least 29 bits*/, std::ratio<60>>
std::chrono::hours         duration</*signed integer type of at least 23 bits*/, std::ratio<3600>>
```

Answer (score 1):

For a short solution use

```
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::this_thread;

void f() {
    sleep_for(200ms);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was learning about chrono library and thought of implementing a sleep function on my own. Here is the code,

```
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>

template <typename rep = std::chrono::seconds::rep, 
          typename period = std::chrono::seconds::period>
void sleep(std::chrono::duration<rep, period> sec) {
    using sleep_duration = std::chrono::duration<long double, std::nano>;

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    long double elapsed_time = 
    std::chrono::duration_cast<sleep_duration>(end - start).count();

    long double sleep_time = 
    std::chrono::duration_cast<sleep_duration>(sec).count();

    while (std::isgreater(sleep_time, elapsed_time)) {
        end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        elapsed_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<sleep_duration>(end - start).count(); 
    }
}
```

We can use it with any `std::chrono::duration` type (By default it takes `std::chrono::seconds` as argument). For example,

```
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>

template <typename rep = std::chrono::seconds::rep, 
          typename period = std::chrono::seconds::period>
void sleep(std::chrono::duration<rep, period> sec) {
    using sleep_duration = std::chrono::duration<long double, std::nano>;

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    long double elapsed_time = 
    std::chrono::duration_cast<sleep_duration>(end - start).count();

    long double sleep_time = 
    std::chrono::duration_cast<sleep_duration>(sec).count();

    while (std::isgreater(sleep_time, elapsed_time)) {
        end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        elapsed_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<sleep_duration>(end - start).count(); 
    }
}

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
int main (void) {
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    
    sleep(5s);  // sleep for 5 seconds
    
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    
    std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << std::fixed;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time was: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end1-start1).count() << "s\n";
    
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    sleep(500000ns);  // sleep for 500000 nano seconds/500 micro seconds
    // same as writing: sleep(500us)
    
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    
    std::cout << "Elapsed time was: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end2-start2).count() << "us\n";
    return 0;
}
```

For more information, visit https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono
and see this cppcon talk of [Howard Hinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant), https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M.
He has two more talks on chrono library. And you can always use the library function, [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)

***Note***: Outputs may not be accurate. So, don't expect it to give exact timings.

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution proposed by @Ben Voigt -- it does not rely on anything outside of C++, but he did not mention an important detail to make the code work.  So I am putting the full code, please notice the line starting with using.

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

...

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
std::this_thread::sleep_for(200ms);
```