# fprintf function not working but it returns positive number

Tags: c++, c, stdio, buffering, printf

I'm using `fprintf` in the following way. Everything seems to be ok but `fprintf` doesn't print to my file at all!

```
fprintf(pFile, "%s\n", "print");
```

Something that is strange is that `fprintf` returns `OK`. it returns `6` in the above code, but not printing to file!

The file is created successfully but is empty.

changing it to `printf` is printing and `OK` too.

Comment: How did you opened pFile ? Did you check the return value when opening the file ?

Comment: Please show the code that is opening the file.

Comment: Are you calling `fclose`? If not, the buffers might not be flushed!

Comment: This can help with Thomas answer if you are not clear about what flushing the buffer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042849/what-does-flushing-the-buffer-mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fprintf` and the other stdio output functions are buffered, which means that the output is first stored in memory, and not actually printed until later. When printing to the screen using standard output, each new line flushes the buffer, so with `printf` you would see the output immediately, but when printing to a file the buffer won't be flushed until you have written (for example) 4096 bytes. You can add `fflush(pFile);` to flush the buffer, if you for some reason need the output to appear on the file quickly.

The buffer is also flushed when calling `fclose`, or closing the file implicitly by properly exiting the program, but if the program keeps running without closing the file, or if it crashes, you will need `fflush` to see the output on the file.