# Odd behavior with stdio.h, VS 2015

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to make a program, and have simplified the code down to the following, to show the part in which the bug lies:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "huh.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, it builds like a charm, with no warnings or errors, but fails to run. After navigating to the exe's directory on command prompt, I run the program and it never prints out `huh.`, and never quits. I have a feeling it is a problem with `stdio.h`, but I am not sure. Any help would be appreciated!

Note: Compiled with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 for Windows Desktop.

Comment: Does it work if you [flush](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15042849/3425536) the output with `endl`: `cout << "huh." << endl;`? Btw the `stdio.h` include is redundant.

Comment: No, still doesn't work. I used stdio.h for another project, I just got rid of all the code that needed it. (So now it is just the bare-bones base.)

Comment: I compiled your code as a *Win32 Console Application* with Visual Studio 2015. Works fine.

Comment: I did the same, and it didn't work on either of my computers. Any ideas?

Comment: turn off your antivirus

Comment: Can you run it in the debugger and step-into  and see where it gets?

Comment: Ohh, antivirus. I will try turning it off tomorrow. I'll report how it works. (I'm in my bed right now.)

Comment: And in the debugger, it just stops at the step where it says *.sln -> *.exe, and displays Window's hour glass. (Sorry I can't remember locations of the files, so that is what the *s represent)

Comment: It was my antivirus. It actually blocked the running of any program from VS 2015. I'll file a report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my issue was what M.M suggested, my antivirus(Avast). I believe it blocks the running of any code from VS 2015, so I'll make a report. I don't think it had anything to do with `stdio.h`.

Thanks to M.M!