# usleep does not work as expected in c++, ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, printing, jquery-animate, usleep

I want to simulate the typing of text (as if someone was typing it on the screen) while printing a string. Simply put, print a character, wait for a short while, and then print the next character and so on.

```
void type(char* str)
{
    if(*str==0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << (char)(*str);
        usleep(200000); // should pause for 0.2 seconds after every print
        type(str+1);
    }
}
```

So, technically **type("hello world")** should print each character of "hello world" with a **0.2 second** gap. Instead, **this waits for n*(0.2) seconds** (n is the length of the string) at the beginning, and then prints the whole string. It does not show this animation effect.

I tried looping, but this problem still persists. So, what's wrong with this code?

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS. GCC v5.3.1 20160413.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of output buffering. You will have to flush the output before sleeping on every iteration.

Comment: Thanks! It works now.

Would you mind giving me a reference where I could learn what flushing is and why I needed to flush the output stream?

Comment: Sure. See [What does flushing the buffer mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15042849/464709)

Comment: Thanks lot! Understood :)