# Unexplained behaviour with sleep functions in C

Tags: c, sleep

I want my program to print a given file but instead of printing it at once I want the characters to appear with a certain interval.

Instead of waiting, for example, 1 second and then printing the character, it seems to wait 1 sec for every character it has to print in the current line and then prints all the characters at once.

I've tried using usleep() and sleep(), before and after the putchar() function, albeit with no success.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char ch;

    if(argc != 2)
    {
    puts("The syntax of the command is incorrect: \n*Program* *file*");
    exit(0);
    }
    if((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == 0)
    {
    puts("Error opening file");
    exit(1);
    }

    while((ch = fgetc(fp))!= EOF)
    {
      switch (ch)
        {
            case ' ': putchar(ch);
                      usleep(1000000/3);
                      break;

            case '\n':putchar(ch);
                      usleep(1000000/2);
                      break;

            default: putchar(ch);
                     usleep(1000000/4);
        }

    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I've read about the sleep function behavior and haven't found anything relevant.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `stdout` is line-buffered.

Comment: Add `fflush(stdout);` after each `putchar`.

Comment: I'm sorry @EOF, can you expand on that statement? I can't quite understand.

Comment: It works perfectly now. Can you explain why it was behaving like that?

Comment: @DiogoMeneses: Output on line-buffered streams is potentially delayed until the stream is flushed, a newline is written to the stream, or input is read from an interactive stream.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense now @EOF

Comment: @DiogoMeneses the characters are buffered and then printed on demand. This increases performance significantly on large outputs. See answers in the this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15042979)