# Why / when is cout buffer automatically flushed?

Tags: c++, buffer, cout

I understand from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042849/what-does-flushing-the-buffer-mean) that if i were to output characters without flushing the buffer ( with `endl` or `cin` ) they wouldn't appear on my console until the program ends.

So i tried to make an infinite loop:

```
for(;;)
{
    std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
}
```

and the same without flushing the buffer:

```
for(;;)
{
    std::cout << "a";
}
```

They both output forever `a`, the only difference i can observe is that the latter version of code has some delay time before it starts outputting the letter. The first one starts immediately.

I was expecting the second one to output the chars only if there was a `break` in the loop, and the program would be terminated.

Comment: No, it fills up the buffer before flushing. The buffer isn't infinite in size.

Comment: "they wouldn't appear on my console until the program ends" - or untill the buffer is full..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that `std::endl`, or the use of `std::cin`, causes a flush to occur, and the contents to be immediately output. `std::endl` is the equivalent of `std::cout.put('\n'); std::cout.flush();`, where as `std::cin` and `std::cerr` are `tie()`d to `std::cout` and therefore any operation to either of those executes `std::cout.flush()` for you.

However, in the second case, `std::cout` still has an underlying output sequence (an `std::streambuf`), which is a specified size. Once this buffer is full, the stream is flushed automatically, and you get the output to the console. Filling up this buffer is what you are seeing with the *delay time* you mentioned.