# Output buffer for terminal is getting flushed in case of both new line and endl. Why?

Tags: c++, buffer, flush

I know that new line character does not flush the output but endl does.

Flushing the buffer means that everything stored in the buffer will be sent to the file which in this case is terminal.

"[it clear the buffer by outputting everything in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042849/what-does-flushing-the-buffer-mean)"

Let's take a reproducible example where I am throwing exception from main program for the runtime to catch.

```
int main()
{
    cout<<"ABC";
    throw 0;
}
```

The above works as expected and I don't see ABC on terminal.

```
int main()
{
    cout<<"ABC"<<endl;
    throw 0;
}
```

The above prints `ABC` which is also fine since we know that endl will flush everything.

But what I don't understand is since `\n` does not flush to terminal, the ouput behvior in the below program should work same as the first one. But **NO** this prints `ABC` on terminal. Doesn't this violate what we read, that `\n` does not flushes the buffer?

```
int main()
{
    cout<<"ABC"<<"\n";
    throw 0;
}
```

Comment: `stdout` is usually line-buffered, so a `\n` flushes it.

Comment: To expand on the comment from @mch, `std::cout` are usually synched to the C output standard system, which uses `stdout` which is line-buffered when connected to an interactive terminal (i.e. not redirected or piped).

Comment: Also note that `std::cout << "ABC\n";` or `std::cout << "ABC" << '\n';` would give the same result. It's not a matter of you using a separate output part.

Comment: So are you saying that this rule of flushing applies only for regular files and not device files like terminal?

Comment: Interactive terminals and consoles are historically line-based. That has been kept up to this day with modern terminal emulator programs.

Comment: Also note that just because `endl` flushes the buffer, that does not mean that it is the *only* time the buffer is flushed. Buffering means that the underlying system decides when to send the data forward, so you cannot say that "No `endl` means that it is an error that it goes to the terminal". Typically this is done when enough data has been gathered, when enough time has passed, or when it for some other reason is performant to do so.

Comment: In that case using a endl or a `\n` should not make any difference right? While writing a program, my interviewer told me not to use `endl` since its costly while using cout. So I wasn't wrong and it wouldn't have made any difference, feel stupid I did not know this to put counter arguments

Comment: That depends on what you were asked to do. If the request was: "Output a newline" and you output "newline and forced flush" then I would say that you failed the task. You can argue that "Oh, but in this specific case newline IS a forced flush (typically)", but you are working with C++ out-streams where you can easily swap out the stream - f.ex. for one where newline is not a forced flush - and then your code is just wrong. Writing code that is "technically correct here, but wrong in any other similar context" is bad when it is possible to write code that is just correct in every context.

Comment: But take that with a grain of salt - I was not there, and I don't know what was said in your interview. :)