# C programming: I want subtract a weight per second

Tags: c, timer, subtraction

I am new in stackoverflow and i am sorry if i make mistakes.

I am starter in C language and i have one project what it needs to subtact a weight per second.For example
Weight: 50kg
Subtract per second 4%

i found this code

```
while(waitFor(1))
{
    *weight=(*weight)-(*weight)*0.4;
}

void waitFor(int secs)
{
    int retTime;
    retTime = time(0) + secs;     // Get finishing time.
    while (time(0) < retTime);    // Loop until it arrives.
}
```

But i dont want to wait x seconds to finish. I want faster solution. Any ideas

**Note: I want to know how much seconds need to make weight 0
Sleep command it is not working in my computer.
**

> For cleaning and disinfecting of the pool dropped into the water of a chemical
>   a solid body. This solid body upon contact with water
>   immediately begins to dissolve, losing weight equal to 4% by mass per second.
>   If the dissolution rate of the chemical remains constant, to implement program
>   will accept the weight of the solid body in grams and displays after how
>   time will completely dissolve. The time is displayed in a "hours: minutes: seconds".
>   For example, if the dissolution time is 3,740 seconds, displaying 01: 02: 20.
>   To calculate the time you need to implement a function which accepts
>   gram and return the three time parameters ie
>   hours, minutes and seconds. Note that the time printed on the main
>   function.

Comment: What about `sleep(1)`?

Comment: What did you mean by faster solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

To find out the number of seconds required for the weight to reach 0:

```
unsigned seconds = 0;
while(*weight != 0){
   *weight -= *weight * 0.04
   seconds++;
   //in case you have the patience to attend:
   sleep(1000); //in milliseconds => 1 second
}
```

*Please note that weight is considered to be a pointer to an integer type.*

Comment: I want to know how much seconds need to make weight 0. Sleep is not working in my computer

Comment: Without any rounding on those calculations, the time should be infinite. For example if you start with 100KG and subtract 10% every second, after 100 seconds you still have 0,002656139889KG. (and goes on forever...)

Comment: Look the question i write the exercise. Also tihs aswer it is not for real seconds.

Comment: @João Neto I am afraid you are wrong. My assumption implies that weight is an integer type ; which means that the value is automatically rounded to the closest integer value.

Comment: @Gabe weight subtract every second?

Comment: @Michael Indeed. Every iteration involves a "pause" of the thread of exactly 1 second.

Comment: Depending on the platform you're working on import unistd.h for UNIX(..) or windows.h for Windows.

Comment: @Gabe I know - your solution is fine by me. :) I just have an issue with @Michael's comment, because I think the solution is not correct by it's own design. (`f(x) = W*(1-L)^t`) has no zeroes, where W is initial weight and L is the percentage loss).

Comment: @Gabe same #include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <unistd.h>

Comment: "sleep" is actually Sleep on Windows

Comment: Here's a nice wrapper: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658386/sleep-function-in-c

Comment: ok i make it Sleep(1000) but i must again wait. If the solid body need over 2 hours to dissolve?

Comment: The Sleep sequence is of course optional. For further processing take advantage of the value of 'seconds'.

Comment: @Gabe Hmm ok the value of seconds in loop it is millisecond?

Comment: No, it is in seconds.

Comment: Ahh ok I spend over 4 hours for something too simple! haha but i learn more about timer thanks dude!

Comment: Please consider rating or marking my code as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can use sleep(int) function in loop it will wait suspend the process up to the integer value.

```
  while((1) && weight > 0)
  {
 sleep(1);
*weight=(*weight)-(*weight)*0.4;
  }
```

it will wait for 1 seconds and subtraction will made, it will run continuously