# Delay in Dev C++

Tags: c++, delay

I have come across to a problem while coding in C++ on Dev C++ compiler. I want to delay my statement to some milliseconds, but the problem is dev doesnt support the dos.h header file and so its contents as well. I had an alternative way for using it with the help of for loop but i aint got its proper syntax in my mind to use it properly. I wish, you folks, might be able to resolve the problem for me. Thanks in Advance..

```
#include <dos.h>

int main(){

delay(1000)
cout << "Hello" 

return 0;
```

Tell me another alternative way for this please.

Comment: It helps to have a name to search for ... and < chrono > is probably the name to research.  It turns out that < thread > also has a function or two of use to you. 
 Review both  on the en.cppreference.com site.  (Hint - you might google for usage of a function called sleep - did you do any research?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sleep function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658386/sleep-function-in-c)

Comment: Thanks alot, bro. I am actually a novice so i didnt make any research as i didnt even knkw what to do. Well i have sorted out the problem, thanks for the help again.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has < thread >

< thread > has "std::this_thread::sleep_for(...)"

Example illustrating the (...)

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
```

The ms of 100 ms comes from

```
using  namespace std::chrono_literals;  // support suffixes like 100ms, 2s, 30 us
```

Probably you also need to include  < chrono >

Comment: Thanks Alot, I have sorted out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the header chrono and thread

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
    using namespace std::this_thread; 
using namespace std::chrono; 
sleep_for(nanoseconds(10));
sleep_until(system_clock::now() + seconds(1));
```

You can change the nanoseconds part to seconds or keep it at nanoseconds, and the number  beside it is the amount of that unit that you can change to any number.

Answer (score -3):

Use empty for loop
for example:

```
for(int i=0; i<10000; i++);
```

Change upper bound according to your need.

Comment: you can also use sleep function from stdlib.h too delay as sleep(500)

Comment: Ues, this is what i was talking about. i just forgot the syntax