# How do I mark a time stamp every minute?

Tags: c

Using c++, usleep() and sleep() don't work and currently the timestamp is being measured hundreds of times a second instead of every minute

```
// CPP program to print current date and time
// using time and ctime.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
int main () {
for( ; ; ){



    // declaring argument of time()
    time_t my_time = time(NULL);

    // ctime() used to give the present time
    printf("%s", ctime(&my_time));

    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "usleep() and sleep() don't work"? Do you get compilation errors? Show the code where you've tried to use them.

Comment: its OSx not windows so sleep() doesn't work, and usleep does work in that the time prints every second but it prints hundreds of entries each time whereas I want one time stamp each minute

Comment: like the code above but with usleep(1000) after the printf command

Comment: Maybe this will help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658386/sleep-function-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658386/sleep-function-in-c)

Comment: `usleep(1000)` waits for 1000 microseconds (0.001 seconds). To wait for one minute you need `usleep(60000000)`.