# fatal error: 'windows.h' file not found #include<windows.h> //for sleep

Tags: c++, macos, include

What can be the alternate of this for macOS? I was making a vaccine management system and now this is the issue I am facing.

Comment: If sleep is all you need, googling would have been faster: [Sleep function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658386/sleep-function-in-c)

Comment: [`windows.h`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows.h) is a Microsoft-specific header for Win32 that only works on windows. You may find suitable alternatives on mac based on what you are looking for.

Comment: Depending on the project it could be easy to remove the windows.h dependency or very hard. If it is the latter wine may help. [https://www.winehq.org/](https://www.winehq.org/) possibly: [https://wiki.winehq.org/Winelib_User%27s_Guide](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winelib_User%27s_Guide)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using platform dependent function to put the thread in sleep, you should use function available in standard C++ library.

C++ provides `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` function to put a thread in sleep.

Please check example here taken from [CppReference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
int main()
{
     using namespace std::chrono_literals;
     std::cout << "Hello waiter\n" << std::flush; auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
     std::this_thread::sleep_for(2000ms);
     auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
     std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> elapsed = end-start;
     std::cout << "Waited " << elapsed.count() << " ms\n";
}
```

Comment: [Looks like we might have to update that cppreference docs page.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37440647/4581301) If `high_resolution_clock` is an alias of `system_clock` the timing result can be hilariously wrong.

Comment: `high_resolution_clock` is not reliable for measuring durations.  It's pretty unreliable in general, despite its impressive-sounding name.  `steady_clock` should be used here.