# C++ Typewriting Effect

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to make typewriting effect print in C++ and the error is the script give me the final result instead of the typewriting effect.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  std::string d1 = "\"Starting in 3, 2, 1...\"";
  for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(d1); i++){
    std::cout << d1[i];
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not `sizeof(d1)` but `d1.size()`

Comment: `sizeof(d1)` gives the size of the object `d1`, not the length of the string it contains. Use `d1.size()` instead

Comment: Decent first effort, but I calculate that your program (it's a program, not a script) is going to take 24 seconds to run, and that's too long.  Do you know about [`usleep`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html)?  But, better still (although a little harder to master), use [`std::chrono_sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for).

Comment: You should include the C++ headers, not the C ones. `#include <cstdlib>`. But I don't think you even need it here.

Comment: You are looping through string so it will basically just print that string again for you

Comment: @MushfiqurRahmanAbir But with a `sleep` between each character, that's the whole point...

Comment: I think that's called "ghost typing"

Answer (score 3):

What with those other problems, everybody seems to have missed the point here, which is that `std::cout` is buffered (on most systems). So it is waiting for the newline before displaying the text. Try calling `std::cout.flush()` before every call to `sleep()`.

Comment: They are all busy to replace a 9 character statement by a 60 character statement :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use `sizeof(d1)` which returns the size in bytes of the string but use `d1.size()` which return the length of the string. Also, I have no idea where did you get that `sleep()` function from. Use `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds({time_in_milliseconds}));` instead (you will need to `#include <thread>`).

### Working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

int main() {
    std::string d1 = "\"Starting in 3, 2, 1...\"";

    for (int i = 0; i < d1.size(); i++) 
    {
        std::cout << d1[i];
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    }
}
```

Comment: `sleep` is [specific to Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html), kind of, but it's widely supported on *nix systems.

Comment: @PaulSanders but you have to admit that thread/chrono line is so much easier to remember :-)

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Sure isn't :)

Comment: Look here how to do it in a simple way with `chrono` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658386/sleep-function-in-c/69722671#69722671